# Down arrow doesn't work unless holding ctrl key

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

As the title indicates, my down arrow key doesn't work with the exception of the keyboard shortcut "ctrl + down" showing the windows of a specific application.

Since it works in this one situation I suspect it isn't a hardware issue.  Additionally pressing the down arrow in an iTerm window makes the terminal completely unresponsive.

Steps I have tried to debug:
 - uninstall all things that may capture keystrokes (karabiner, logitech mouse software, etc)
 - run xev to show key presses, it does not show a key press when the down arrow is pressed

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!